# Which primepowers can divide $3^k-2$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I tried to get a survey which primepowers $p^n$ divide $3^k-2$ 
for some natural k.

PARI has a function znlog, but there are some issues :

Instead of returning 0, if the discrete logarithm does not exist, 
an error occurs. So I cannot filter out, for which primes $3^n\equiv2\ (mod\ p)$ 
has a solution. znlog(2,Mod(3,11)) returns the wrong solution 7, if the
order is omitted and returns an error again, if it is added.
Of course, I can use brute force to filter out the primes, but I
would like to have a better method. This leads to my question :

How can I find out efficiently for which prime powers $p^n$ the equation 
$3^k \equiv 2\ (mod\ p^n)$ has a solution (I need not know, if 
the solution is unique).

It seems that for arbitary high powers of 5 and 7, there is a solution.
If so, is there a simple explanation, why ?

Comment: Can you write a function that catches the error, and returns "true" if the log exists and "false" if it doesn't?

Comment: @hurkyl I do not think, that this is possible. PARI simply outputs a message, why it does not work.

Comment: It seems that $3^k\equiv 2\ (mod\ p^n)$ is solveable, if $3^k\equiv 2\ mod(\ p)$ is solveable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your last question:

It well known that if $a$ is a primitive root mod $p^2$ then $a$ is a primitive root mod $p^n$ for all $n\ge 2$.

$3$ is a primitive root mod $5^2$ and mod $7^2$. This explains why $3^k\equiv 2 \bmod p^n$ can be solved for $p=5$ and $p=7$ for all $n$.

Comment: If $3^k\equiv2\ (mod\ p)$ has a solution, can we conclude that 3 must be a primitive root mod p ?

Comment: @Peter, no, we cannot.

Comment: But if 3 is a primitive root, the equation has a solution, right ?

Comment: @Peter, yes, if $3$ is a primitive root then all equations $3^k \equiv b $ have solutions, for all $b$ coprime with $p^n$.

Comment: For a list of primes of with primitive root $3$, see http://oeis.org/A019334. For all these, $3$ is also a primitive root mod $p^2$, but I did not find an explicit list.